# How to make a exception that inform the user that the number they input is out of range?

Tags: java

We were given a task by my teacher that will ask user for an input of an integer 1 to 50, I've nearly completed my code but the only thing missing is a catch on informing the user if they input more than 50. Can you help me what is the missing in my code. I've read my handouts there is no such thing as an Exception that limiting a certain amount of integer or whatsoever.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int answer = 28;
    int attempts = 0;
    boolean condition = false;

    System.out.println("Guess a Number 1 - 50:");
    
    do {
        condition = true;
        try {
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            
            if(input > answer) {
                System.out.println("Too Big");
                System.out.println(); //Spacing
                System.out.println("Guess a Number 1 - 50:");
                attempts++;
            } else if (input < answer) {
                System.out.println("Too Small");
                System.out.println(); //Spacing
                System.out.println("Guess a Number 1 - 50:");
                attempts++;
            } else {
                int totalA = attempts + 1;
                System.out.println(); //Spacing
                System.out.println("Congratulations! "+ "You attempted " + totalA + " times." );
            } 
            
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Numbers only");
            System.out.println(); //Spacing
            System.out.println("Guess a Number 1 - 50:");
            condition = true;
            scan.nextLine();
        } 
        
    } while(condition);



}
```

Comment: you shouldn't. this should be a condition, not an exception

Comment: @Stultuske Why not?

Comment: `if (notInRange()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is not in range");`

Comment: What's the purpose of an exception? An exception is a way of having a method tell the caller of that method that something went wrong. This application doesn't involve a method. Exceptions are not things that should be presented to an end user.

Comment: @m0skit0 exceptions should be thrown because of "exceptional" occurences. Somebody entering a number when asked to enter a number, is not an exceptional occurence. Even if you follow your logic, you still need the condition. Why not just: correct = false; while (!correct ) number = input(); correct = validateInput(correct); if (!correct) print "provide valid input";

Comment: @Stultuske Despite their name, exceptions are not for exceptional cases. In fact `nextInt()` is throwing an exception already. Exceptions are a mechanism for [indicating conditions that a reasonable application might want to catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html).

Comment: @m0skit0 and why would an application "want to catch that"? Exceptions are to indicate something unforeseen has happened that causes a problem. Something like this is not 'unforeseen', nor should it be treated as such.

Comment: @Stultuske The same way it catches InputMismatchException. Makes sense to just add that to the catch block. In any case this might be a requirement for a homework for practicing how to throw and catch your own exceptions. That said, I personally would not throw an exception, although I don't see it as a bad practice in this case.

Comment: @m0skit0 I didn't say "how", I said "why", there's a difference. There's no need at all to use an exception here. Just use a simple condition, the same you'll need to use if you want to throw an Exception, and you're done

Comment: @Stultuske I'm answering why, not how.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is very important that you know that you can create your own `Exception` classes that have their specific messages and uses.

For example:

```java
public class NumberTooHighException extends Exception { 
    public NumberTooHighException() {
        super("The number inputted is wayyyy to high...");
    }
}
```

And then you can use your `Exception` as any other:

```java
if(input > 50)
{
    throw new NumberTooHighException(); // Here you throw it...
}
```

And if you wanna `catch` it, you wrap your code in a `try-catch` block. More on that [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/try-catch-block).

But as the comments hint:

> An exception is a way of having a method tell the caller of that
> method that something went wrong

So try to avoid using them for specific use cases (as this one for example). Even though yours is homework/schoolwork.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to throw an exception from your code, you need to do this ...

```
 if(input > answer) {
  ...
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is too big");
  ...
 } else if (input < answer) {
   ...
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is too small");

  ...
  } else {
  ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int answer = 28;
        int attempts = 0;
        int maxNumber = 50;
        boolean condition = false;

        System.out.println("Guess a Number 1 - 50:");

        do {
            condition = true;
            try {
                int input = scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();

                if (input > maxNumber){
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }else if(input > answer) {
                    System.out.println("Too Big");
                    System.out.println(); //Spacing
                    System.out.println("Guess a Number 1 - 50:");
                    attempts++;
                } else if (input < answer) {
                    System.out.println("Too Small");
                    System.out.println(); //Spacing
                    System.out.println("Guess a Number 1 - 50:");
                    attempts++;
                } else {
                    int totalA = attempts + 1;
                    System.out.println(); //Spacing
                    System.out.println("Congratulations! "+ "You attempted " + totalA + " times." );
                }

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Numbers only");
                System.out.println(); //Spacing
                System.out.println("Guess a Number 1 - 50:");
                condition = true;
                scan.nextLine();
            }

        } while(condition);



    }
```